# Como incluir uma nova nota em um array?

Tags: java, array

> Faça um programa que calcule o mostre a média aritmética de N
>   notas utilizando *array*.

Eu estou tentando fazer isso:

```
package exer4;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Exer4 {

   public static void main(String[] args){

   int nota[] = {4,5,7,4,3,6,6,8,3,4};
       int perguntar = in.nextInt();
   int aluno = 0;
   int soma = 0;

   while(aluno < 10){
    System.out.println("Aluno: " + aluno + " Nota: " + nota[aluno]);
    aluno++;
   }
   for(int i = 0; i < nota.length; i++){
    soma = soma + nota[i];

    System.out.println(soma);
   }        

}
}
```

Fiz desse outro modo:

```
package exer4;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Exer4 {

    public static void main(String[] args){
       Scanner in = new Scanner (System.in);

    int nota[] = {1,4,5,7,6, inserir};
        int inserir = in.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Digite as suas notas e espere a media");
        System.out.println("Sua nota pode ser:" + nota);
        System.out.println("Sua media pode ser:" + nota / 2);

    }
 }
```

Estou tentando desse outro modo também:

```
package exer4;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Exer4 {

    public static void main(String[] args){
       Scanner in = new Scanner (System.in);

    int nota[] = {1,4,5,7,6, inserir};
        nota[0] = in.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Digite as suas notas e espere a media");
        System.out.println("Sua nota pode ser:" + nota);
        System.out.println("Sua media pode ser:" + nota / 2);

    }
 }
```

Comment: Alguma das respostas resolveu sua dúvida? Acha que pode aceitar uma delas? Veja o [tour] como fazer isso, se ainda não o fez. Você ajudaria a comunidade identificando qual foi a melhor solução para você. Pode aceitar apenas uma delas. Mas pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo (quando tiver pontuação suficiente).

Answer (score 2):

Não pode. Você tem algumas opções, criar um *array* bem grande suficiente para todas elas, o que pode provocar um consumo de memória desnecessário, mas que não faz diferença real em muitos casos, ainda mais em Java e para um exercício. Ou fazer o que todo mundo faz que é usar uma lista no lugar de um *array*, que costuma ser recomendado mesmo que não precise adicionar nada. Só não vou falar que em Java não tem desvantagem alguma porque é uma linguagem verbosa e exige escrever muito mais código para manipular uma lista do que uma *array*, mas em outras linguagens não tem desvantagem real sensível, e tem vantagens. Uma outra alternativa seria recriar o *array* maior e copiando tudo de uma para o outro toda vez que não couber novos elementos, que no fundo é o que a lista faz, só que ela faz de um jeito bem pensado que você provavelmente não fará.

Um *array* não pode crescer de tamanho, depois que cria ele fica com aquele tamanho.

Porém o enunciado não pede para adicionar novos itens no *array*, ele pede apenas para criar um *array* com uma certa quantidade de elementos. Então peça quantos elementos terá, o tal do `N` que o enunciado fala e depois crie o *array* com o tamanho necessário.

Todos códigos parecem ter coisas meio sem sentido como inicializar um *array* que não usará esses valores, ou pedir um dado que não é usado, ou preferir um `while` onde um `for` funciona melhor, ou usar um laço extra onde a operação pode ser resolvido no mesmo laço já usado antes e não fez a média, além de imprimir as uma acumulando em cada passo, enfim, o código está bem caótico. O segundo e terceiro código não fazem sentido.

Seria algo assim:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class Exer4 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner in = new Scanner (System.in);
        int alunos = in.nextInt();
        int notas[] = new int[alunos];
        int soma = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < alunos; i++) {
            notas[i] = in.nextInt();
            soma += notas[i];
        }
        System.out.println(soma / alunos);
    }
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/jE08lt). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/@maniero/InitializationVariablejava). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Java/Array/InitializationVariable.java).